# Ajax Combobox button disappearing in a tab container when page refresh happening

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, wss

i am having a tabcontainer with 3 tab panels.in the first tab panel i have combobox.for every tab panel there was a save button.when we click on save button page will refresh.When i click on save button in first tab where combobox there i m not getting any problem.
Where when i click on other tab save button page getting refresh but when i came to tab1 the combobox dropdown button is disappearing.

I did put this tab container in Update panel i tried Updatemode="Conditional" but it was working only for postback not for entire page refresh.

Please help on this issue

Comment: Standard DropDownList?  What kind of combo, what kind of tab container?  Are these Ajax Control toolkit controls?

Comment: Yes It was a Ajax Combobox...i used ajax tool kit 3.0 for Ajax Combobox and Ajax tabcontainer

Answer (score 0):

adding this css to the combobox fixed the problem for me....

```
.mycombostyle .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer .ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer button
{ margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  background-image: url(../Images/AjaxControlToolKit/ComboBox/icarus-arrow.png); 
  background-position: top left; 
  border: 1px black solid; 
  height: 20px !important; 
  width: 25px !important;}  

.mycombostyle ul
{ position: absolute !important; 
  min-width: 270px; 
  width:auto !important;     
  min-height: 150px; /*height:auto !important;*/  
  overflow-y: auto !important;}
```